# Select only the name of the column of the tables implemented by the inheritance of the table in SQL Server 2014

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, listview, inheritance, sqldatasource

I have a question about selecting only the **name** of the column of the tables implemented by the inheritance of the table in SQL Server 2014.

I.e. having four types of person (**students**, **teachers**, **employees** and **supervisor**) and all of them containing an `id` for each type of person inherited from the `Person` table and also a later that **name** must be selected and displayed.

Table `TypePerson`:

```
CREATE TABLE [TypesPerson] 
(
    [typePersonID] INT NOT NULL,
    [typePerson] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TypesPerson] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([typePersonID] ASC)
);
```

`Insert` for type of person:

```
INSERT INTO [TypesPerson]
    SELECT 1,'students' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'teachers' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'employer' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'supervisor'
```

Table `Person`:

```
CREATE TABLE [Person] 
(
    [personID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [typePersonID] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PersonID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UN_Person_Type] UNIQUE ([typePersonID])
);
```

Table `Students` extends `Person`:

```
CREATE TABLE [Students] 
(
    [personID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [typePersonID] AS 1 PERSISTED, --type person = 1
    [name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Students] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PersonID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Students] FOREIGN KEY ([typePersonID])
    REFERENCES [Person] ([typePersonID]),
);
```

Table `Teachers` extends `Person`:

```
CREATE TABLE [Teachers] 
(
    [PersonID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [typePersonID] AS 2 PERSISTED, --type person = 2
    [name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Teachers ] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PersonID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Teachers ] FOREIGN KEY ([typePersonID])
    REFERENCES [Person] ([typePersonID]),
);
```

Table `Employers` extends `Person`:

```
CREATE TABLE [Employers] 
(
    [personID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [typePersonID] AS 3 PERSISTED, --type person = 3
    [name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PersonID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Employers] FOREIGN KEY ([typePersonID])
    REFERENCES [Person] ([typePersonID]),
);
```

`Insert` data to create the person with type:

```
INSERT INTO [Person] ([typePersonID]) VALUES (1); --students
INSERT INTO [Person] ([typePersonID]) VALUES (2); --teachers
INSERT INTO [Person] ([typePersonID]) VALUES (3); --employer
INSERT INTO [Person] ([typePersonID]) VALUES (4); --supervisor
```

Insert data to create students, teachers and employers:

```
INSERT INTO [Students]  ([name])  VALUES ('John'); --students
INSERT INTO [Teachers]  ([name])  VALUES ('Robert'); --teachers
INSERT INTO [Employers] ([name])  VALUES ('Ciara'); --employer
INSERT INTO [Supervisor] ([name]) VALUES ('Renata'); --supervisor
```

When I select just the name using this scripts

```
SELECT st.name, ts.name, es.name,  sp.name
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Students   st ON p.personID= st.personID
INNER JOIN Teachers   ts ON p.personID= ts.personID
INNER JOIN Employers  es ON p.personID= es.personID
INNER JOIN Supervisor sp ON p.personID= sp.personID;
```

the result is

[image]

and I want to show all these **names** in a ListView when I use `<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" />` to get the data from database and `<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" />` to display all the **names** in a horizontal position, as shown in the picture below

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will have to use unpivot. http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/converting-rows-to-columns-pivot-and-columns-to-rows-unpivot-in-sql-server.html

Comment: Your `Person` table design allows to insert at most 4 rows, one for each "type of person".

Comment: @AlexKudryashev, I don´t put because it´s much code in question and I found the answer with merit by Aditya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Pivot` you can Achieve your result. But in simple way you can try it.

```
SELECT st.name Name
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Students   st ON p.personID= st.personID

union
SELECT  ts.name Name
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Teachers   ts ON p.personID= ts.personID
union

SELECT  es.name Name
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Employers  es ON p.personID= es.personID
union

SELECT   sp.name Name
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Supervisor sp ON p.personID= sp.personID
```

Comment: thanks and it´s work perfectly, the ListView show all name in horizontal,

Answer (score 1):

You'll be surprised when you try this:

```
SELECT t.typePerson, sp.name
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN [TypesPerson] as t ON p.[typePersonID] = t.[typePersonID]
INNER JOIN Supervisor sp ON p.personID= sp.personID;
```

The problem is that you have two problems: 
1. Duplication of data: `typePersonID` stored twice for the same individual.
2. Your `personID` in `Person` does not have any correlation with `personID` in other tables.

Essentially, it is better to have **ONLY ONE** `Person` table, just add name column there. It will solve all your problems.

Also, Instead of

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_UN_Person_Type] UNIQUE ([typePersonID])
```

put

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_TypesPerson] FOREIGN KEY ([typePersonID])
REFERENCES [TypesPerson] ([typePersonID]),
```